# PostgreSql Query, Performance NOT IN, LEFT OUTER JOIN

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance

I have Table employee, Table sport that have n to m relations, that's means, i also have one more table, let's say table emp_sport

table employee

```
emp_id emp_name
------------------
e1 name1
e2 name2
e3 name3
e4 name4

table sport
sport_id sport_name
---------------------
sp1 spName1
sp2 spName2
sp3 spName3

table emp_sport
emp_id sport_id
-------------------
e1   sp1
e1   sp2
e1   sp3
e2   sp2
```

i want to select data from employee like this

```
select distinct(e.emp_id), e.emp_name 
from employee e 
where e.emp_id not in (select sp.emp_id from sport_emp sp where sp.sport_id = 'sp1')
```

the result, i have

```
e2 name2
e3 name3
e4 name4
```

the problem is, when i have very huge data in table employee and also emp_sport, query was very slow.

Comment: It's usually better to use `NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 WHERE ...)` than `NOT IN (SELECT ...)`. Also, your `NOT IN (SELECT ...)` will probably produce unexpected results unless `sp.emp_id` is `NOT NULL`. For query performance questions you need to include more information; see http://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info for what you need to add by *editing your question* (not comments).

Answer (score 0):

Always use joins if possible. Subquery will always be a reason of lack of performance.

**Try This**

```
select e."emp_id",e."emp_name"
from "employee" e
inner join "emp_sport" es on es."emp_id"=e."emp_id"
where es."sport_id"='sp1'
group by e."emp_id",e."emp_name"
```

Comment: Actually, a subquery is frequently optimized into a join anyway. You can usually write it however you find most readable, though there are certainly exceptions. A `NOT EXISTS` query, for example, typically optimizes into a left anti-join.

Comment: And a join is not necessary a replacement for a (co-related) sub-query. It might return different results

Comment: thx u fro your answer, actually i want the oposite result from your code above, 
SELECT e."emp_id",e."emp_name" 
FROM "employee" e
LEFT OUTER JOIN "emp_sport" es 
on es."emp_id"=e."emp_id" and es."sport_id"='sp1'
WHERE e."emp_id" IS null